# Java SWT How do I properly pass input and output between UI and code?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I'm making my first attempt at passing information between UI and code.  I've posted what I've done so far but am having difficulty finding the proper way to pass information back out without appending the current text.

I understand this is beginner stuff and would also appreciate direction towards a tutorial geared specifically for passing information back and forth between UI and code.

```
public class UserInterface {
    private Shell shell;
    public static void main(){
        Display display = new Display();
        new UserInterface(display);
        display.dispose();      
    }

    public UserInterface(Display display){
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(400, 250);
        initUI();
        center(shell);
        shell.open();
        while(!shell.isDisposed()){
            if(!display.readAndDispatch()){
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    public void initUI(){
        final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
        text.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 18);

        Label lbl1 = new Label(shell, SWT.BEGINNING);
        lbl1.setBounds(20, 50, 500, 50);
        lbl1.setText("(1) Enter number.\n(2) Click next to enter another number\n(3) Click done to find LCM");

        final Text display = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
        display.setBounds(20, 110, 360, 100);

        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setBounds(140, 16, 100, 35);
        button.setText("Button");

        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){
            //display.setText("");
            String output = text.getText();
            display.setText(output);
            }
        });
    }

    public void center(Shell shell){
        Rectangle bds = shell.getMonitor().getBounds();
        Point p = shell.getSize();
        int xPos = (bds.width - p.x) / 2;
        int yPos = (bds.height - p.y) / 2;
        shell.setBounds(xPos, yPos, p.x, p.y);      
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to append, then don't use `Text#append(String)` but rather `Text#setText(String)`.

Comment: @Baz This is what happens when you post before you think.  Thanks Baz.

Comment: Mind if I create an answer? Alternatively, feel free to delete your question.

Comment: @Baz oddly, using setText(String) still "appends" whatever was originally in the Text box.  I;ve gotten around this by using display.setText("").  But logically, why how come when I reassign the setText, it adds onto what is already there instead of completely replacing it?

Comment: Just tested it here myself and it doesn't append. Can you update your code snippet here with what you have right now?

Comment: Ah, see Javadoc of `Text#setText(String)`: "Sets the contents of the receiver to the given string. **If the receiver has style `SINGLE`** and the argument contains multiple lines of text, **the result of this operation is undefined and may vary from platform to platform**." Do you need `SWT.SINGLE`?

Comment: I've updated the code and commented out the line that clears the display.  when you ask if I need SWT.SINGLE, I'm not sure what the alternative would be.  SWT.NONE? I tried that. Doesn't work

Comment: I also would like to know how to have the Text box act as the console.  So that I can just spit the code output straight to the UI.  Is that possible?

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: yes. I commented two days prior. I was waiting for your response.  is it not showing for you?

Comment: I think my answer solves all your problems. If not, please repeat your question, since I'm not sure which comment you are referring to.

Comment: this one 'I've updated the code and commented out the line that clears the display. when you ask if I need SWT.SINGLE, I'm not sure what the alternative would be. SWT.NONE? I tried that. Doesn't work '

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer at all?

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you an idea. It has two `Text` widgets. One of them will act as a console (text appended) and the other one will show the last text you added to the console. Just click the button to add text:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP);
    text.setEditable(false);
    final Text lastAppend = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    lastAppend.setEditable(false);

    Button button = new Button(shell,SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Add new line");

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        private int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            String append = "TEST " + counter++ + "\n";
            text.append(append);
            lastAppend.setText(append);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(300, 300);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]